# multiselect pick list - LC and Visualforce component

Tags: lightning, visualforce-component, multi-select, lighting-web-component

I basically need to build a multi-select picklist component that works both in Lightning and Classic.

There're already solutions available for both scenario, LC embedded in FlexiPage and Visualforce component for Classic:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/example

https://github.com/metadaddy/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist

Do you think that a "hybrid solution", using both components, might be viable in this particular scenario?

Thanks for helping

Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

You can run Lightning Components (both Aura and LWC) in a Visualforce page using [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm). There's some complications with it, such as you need a Lightning Out App (LOA), and you're only allowed on LOA per page, so if you get in the habit of this, you might need to create multiple LOA to create bundles of components you want to load, but it's a viable alternative. That aside, Lightning Out is a great alternative to maintaining two separate versions of the code. You can also just write the entire UI in Lightning and then directly expose those in Visualforce with Lightning Out. The low-maintenance route here is to just use Lightning for everything, and export it to Classic as you need to.

Comment: Thank you, Lighting out seems the best solution here